# Returning a Javascript Object in a function

Tags: javascript, scope, addeventlistener

To practice my knowledge of Javascript objects, I made a very simple program:

```
const male = document.querySelector('.male');
const female = document.querySelector('.female');

/* Person constructor */
function Person (gender) {
    this.gender = gender;

}

Person.prototype.bio = function() {
    alert('This person is ' + this.gender + '.');
};

/* Create person */
male.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let male1 = new Person('male');

    return male1;
});

female.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let female1 = new person('female');

    return female1;
});
```

However, I've run into a scope issue: I cannot call the male1 or female1 objects in global scope. Running

```
male1;
```

in the browser console returns the following error:

```
ReferenceError: male1 is not defined
```

How do I properly return the new objects, male1 and female1, so that I can access them in the global scope?

Comment: the usual way is to store the variable in the global scope, and update it from your click listeners, rather than return it

Comment: What is it that you want to do in global scope that you can't do in the event listener callback?

Comment: male1 scope is defined inside of the function. It can not be referenced outside of the function. That is how variable scoping works.

Comment: One thing you may need to answer in order to provide a proper solution is whether you want single `Person` instances for each gender, or you want to recreate them each time the elements are clicked. Right now you are instantiating new `Person`s each time you click.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, then the general pattern when working with data/variables in relation to an event handler is to declare those variables outside the scope of that event handler (ie in the "global" scope as shown below), rather than to return that variable from your event handler:

```js
const male = document.querySelector('.male');
const female = document.querySelector('.female');

// Declare male1,female1 in global scope
let male1;
let female1;

/* Person constructor */
function Person (gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
    
}

Person.prototype.bio = function() {
    alert('This person is ' + this.gender + '.');
};

/* Create person */
male.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    // update global variables like so
    male1 = new Person('male');
    
    // return male1;
});

female.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    // update global variables like so
    female1 = new Person('female');

    //return female1;
});

// Added this to demonstrate how global variables are updated
// after click events are fired
setInterval(function() {
  console.log('male1',male1);
  console.log('female1',female1);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<button class="male">Male</button>
<button class="female">Female</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Because you are creating the objects inside functions, the objects only exist within the scope of the functions and are not accessible outside of them. You could try making global variables and assigning them inside the function:

```
var male1;
var female1;

/* Create person */
male.addEventListener('click', function() {
    male1 = new Person('male');
});

female.addEventListener('click', function() {
    female1 = new person('female');
});
```