# How to open and close connection with Javascript elements

Tags: javascript, button, socket.io, scope

I have a relatively simple question as still amatuer in JS.

Imagine, I have a class that establishes and closes a socket connection:

```
class mySocket {

  constructor(){
    this.socket = io();
  }

  // button1 logic
  reciveData(){
    this.socket.on("updateData", function (msg) {
      console.log("Received Data :: " + msg);
    });
  }

  // button2 logic
  closeConnection(){
    this.socket.close();
  };
  
  // button3 logic
  static reloadConnection() {
    location.reload();
  };

}
```

I want to make buttons that would implement different methods on instances of `mySocket`.
In example, I may implement `button1`.

```
var button1 = document.getElementById("oneButton");

button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var mysocket = new mySocket();
  mysocket.reciveData();
});
```

I've stucked with `button2` in JS.

All my `botton2` attempts do not see the instance of `mySocket` created by `button1`. Now I use `button3` with static method as a workaround, but it's not what I'd like to have. (Buttons as controls are not critical, it can be anything that implements the logic, i.e. toggles etc.)

PS. (May be I approach the problem in a wrong way altogether?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try taking your socket variable out of the first listener like this:

```js
const button1 = document.getElementById("oneButton");
let mysocket; // Initialization of the variable 'mysocket'

button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  mysocket = new mySocket(); // Initialization of the class 'mysocket'
  mysocket.reciveData(); // Call the method reciveData
});

button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (!(mysocket instanceof mySocket)) return console.log("The first button has not been pressed"); // If the mysocket variable is not an instance of your class mySocket, therefore your class mySocket has not been initialized in the variable, so the button has not been pressed.

  mysocket.closeConnection(); // Otherwise, we close the connection
});
```

Comment: it is a kind of `global` scope in JS?

Comment: You declare the variable outside of any event or function context, which ensures that the variable can be used throughout your file.

The 'let' keyword prevents the variable from being a constant, only the fact that it is outside of all functions ensures its ability to be modified and used in the entire file only.

So yes, it can look like Python's `global`.

Comment: your solution is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620070/returning-a-javascript-object-in-a-function). What can be wrong. May be I should use some `push()` method?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do and how you plan to do it.